# How to tweak this query to make the stored procedure more efficient

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2016 Enterprise on Azure:

I've inherited a stored procedure that is a linear list of `UPDATE` statements. It looks like this:

```
-- copy Country info from SourceReference table to Data table
UPDATE d
SET d.SourceCountry = dbo.SourceReference.Country
FROM data.capture d
INNER JOIN dbo.sourcereference ON d.tasksourceid = dbo.SourceReference.SourceId

-- copy ProductCategory info from SourceReference table to Data table
UPDATE d
SET d.ProductCategory = dbo.SourceReference.ProductCategory
FROM data.capture d
INNER JOIN dbo.sourcereference ON d.tasksourceid = dbo.SourceReference.SourceId

-- copy SourceCategory info from SourceReference table to Data table
UPDATE d
SET d.SourceCategory = dbo.SourceReference.SourceCategory
FROM data.capture d
INNER JOIN dbo.sourcereference ON d.tasksourceid = dbo.SourceReference.SourceId

-- copy Region info from SourceReference table to Data table
UPDATE d
SET d.SourceRegion = dbo.SourceReference.Region
FROM data.capture d
INNER JOIN dbo.sourcereference ON d.tasksourceid = dbo.SourceReference.SourceId

-- copy Agency info from SourceReference table to Data table
UPDATE d
SET d.Agency = dbo.SourceReference.Agency
FROM data.capture d
INNER JOIN dbo.sourcereference ON d.tasksourceid = dbo.SourceReference.SourceId
```

This stored procedure currently takes 5.5 hours to run - the table that it operates on is 4 millions rows. That means that each `UPDATE` statement has to iterate over all 4 million rows, then the next, then the next, etc.

How incredibly inefficient! But I need guidance on how to optimize these statements to make the procedure more efficient. Is there a way to combine all of those `UPDATE` statements so that each record gets all 5 columns populated on the first pass?

Comment: First step is to look at your SQL Plans, and see if there are indexes that will make things more efficient.  Then, if your joins are all identical, set everything in one set statement, each clause separated by commas. But definitely look at your plans and indexes. For example, make sure you have indexes on tasksourceid and sourceid

Answer (score 4):

Assuming all tables and conditions are the same for all update statements (as they appear to be in the question), instead of using an update statement for each column separately, use a single update statement for all columns at once:

```
UPDATE d
SET d.SourceCountry = s.Country,
    d.ProductCategory = s.ProductCategory,
    d.SourceCategory = s.SourceCategory,
    d.SourceRegion = s.Region,
    d.Agency = s.Agency
FROM data.capture as d
INNER JOIN dbo.sourcereference as s ON d.tasksourceid = s.SourceId
```

Comment: And in addition, I would also check to ensure the foreign key column involved in this `JOIN` is properly indexed (most likely, this would be `d.tasksourceid` - assuming that `s.SourceId` is the primary key of `sourcereference`)

Comment: Ok great, so it's as simple as comma-separating the columns.  Fantastic!  I will try this and assuming it works as expected I will mark it as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I will double-check on the indexing but I do believe these columns are already indexed.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I unfortunately marked this as the answer prematurely.  While the query does achieve the same result as the one in the original question, it doesn't do so in any less time, which is why the question was posed.  The suggested columns are definitely indexed, so the only step I haven't taken yet is, as suggested, to examine the SQL plans.  Otherwise, I don't understand how this could be taking almost 6 hours to run.

Comment: This is strange. It should take considerably less time as it's a single statement vs. 5 statements with basically the same plan. I was expecting this to run about 5 times faster.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I know!  I was very surprised!  I ran it twice just to make sure.  First run took 5 hours 52 minutes.  2nd run took 5 hours 26 minutes.

Comment: Can you post the execution plans for both versions? (single query and multiple queries)

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes I will.  These are both run as Stored Procedures by the way, which I know makes getting the execution plan different. Do I need to let the query/procedure finish running before saving the execution plan, or can I execute it, let it run a few seconds, cancel it, and then grab the execution plan?

Comment: I'm not sure about Azure, in non-cloud versions you can show estimated query plan without running, or run to end and show actual execution plan.